# Applying a 2D function to a 4D tensor PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I got a 2D function that takes a matrix - 2D tensor with shape (28, 28)
and I got a tensor, lets say (64, 10, 28, 28) - it's a tensor that contains a batch of 64 images that passed through a (10 kernels) conv2d layer.

Now, I want to activate on the last two dimentions of the tensor, the (28,28) bit, a 2D function.

Now I did that in a very inefficient way:

```
def activation_func(input):

    for batch_idx in range(input.shape[0]):
        for channel_inx in range(input.shape[1]):       
            input[batch_idx][channel_inx] = 2D_function(input[batch_idx][channel_inx])

    return input
```

which is highly inefficient as I noticed.
is there any way of doing this efficiently?

I can write the entire code If necessary

EDIT:

```
def 2D_function(input):
    global indices # yes I know, I will remove this global stuff later
    # indices = [(i, j) for i in range(1, 28, 4) for j in range(1, 28, 4)]

    for x, y in indices:
        relu_decision = relu(input[x, y]) # standard relu - relu(x)=(x>1)*x
        if not relu_decision:
            # zero out the patch
            input[x - 1: x + 3, y - 1: y + 3] = 0
    return input
```

Comment: Indeed, I think it would be relevant to know what `2D_function` is here. As what you're asking here is to vectorized the function to be a batch/channel-wise operator.

Comment: I will add the code @Ivan Code added

Comment: Could you not replace that function with a [`nn.conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) maybe?

Comment: @Ivan I think I can do that If I can figure out a way to get each Kernel (a, a) "window slide" multiplication (I don't know how to phrase it) to correspond with an entire (a, a) patch in the result. and hard code a kernel to be all zeros except the center

Comment: @Ivan my end goal is to reduce the number of relu operations, So actually I don't know if it's better to use a conv2d layer

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you provide a minimal example that would explicit your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, I use a Kronecker product trick:

```py
import torch

torch.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)  # you can better see how the mask is shaped

# simulating an input
input = torch.rand(1, 1, 28, 28) - 0.5


ids = torch.meshgrid((torch.arange(1, 28, 4), torch.arange(1, 28, 4)))

# note that relu(x) = (x > 0.) * x, so adjust it to your needs
relus = torch.nn.functional.relu(input[(slice(None), slice(None), *ids)]).to(bool)

A = torch.ones(4, 4)
# generate a block matrix with ones in positions where blocks are set to 0 in correspondence of relus = 0
mask = torch.kron(relus, A)
print(mask.shape)
output = input * mask

print(mask[0, 0])
print(output[0, 0])
```

Comment: Amazing !! I extended this method into 4 dimentions and it works perfectly ! thank you!